# Understanding Ethereum network fees for tax purposes

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, capital-gains-tax, ethereum

*My question is in relation to UK tax as [explained in this document](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/tax-on-cryptoassets/cryptoassets-for-individuals), however it should be applicable to other jurisdictions as well.*

Ethereum is a platform for decentralised finance. Unlike Bitcoin, developers can build complex applications on top of the base layer, such as:

1. USD Coin, an [ERC20](https://www.investopedia.com/news/what-erc20-and-what-does-it-mean-ethereum/) representation of the US dollar created by Coinbase and Circle
2. [Uniswap](https://uniswap.exchange), an automated token exchange where you can buy and sell Ether (the native token of the Ethereum blockchain) for other ERC20-tokens

Imagine that I bought 1.01 Ether on Coinbase last year, withdrew it to my Ethereum wallet (such as [MetaMask](https://metamask.io)) and sold 1 Ether on Uniswap in exchange for 100 USDC.

Here's the catch. For my transaction to be included in the blockchain, I had to pay a network fee in the form of [gas](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/g/gas-ethereum.asp), which is denominated in Ether. Although the costs was much less, suppose that I paid 0.01 Ether for my Uniswap trade.

So I got approximately $100 worth of value in exchange for 1 Ether, but I also paid approximately $1 (the 0.01 Ether) for my transaction to be processed by the blockchain.

Now, the following statements are simultaneously true:

1. I'm allowed to deduct any transaction fees from my proceeds
2. [Making a payment with Ether tokens is considered a disposal of Ether tokens](https://www.reddit.com/r/UKPersonalFinance/comments/g8m7v5/personal_wallet_transfer_fees_in_relation_to_uk/)

**Therefore, the network fee CANNOT be deducted from my proceeds, because it's offset by a disposal of Ether of the same amount, which happened at the exact same time.**

The rationale would've been the same if I bought 1 Ether with 100 USDC and paid 0.01 Ether for the network fee, with the only change being that the fee couldn't have been added to the cost basis.

I think this is a bit like buying or selling gold to a broker and paying the brokerage fees directly in gold.

Is my rationale correct?

Comment: you're trying to work out CGT here, right?

Comment: Yes, @GS-ApologisetoMonica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to work out CGT, I don't see how your two statements cause you a problem.

As you say, making a payment with Ether tokens is considered a disposal. Make up some value for the payment you made, i.e. the transaction fee. Call it x.

Now, you must have paid a certain amount for your 1.01 Ether. Let's say $80 to keep things fairly simple.

You've made $100 for selling 1.00 Ether, plus x for disposing of 0.01 Ether, and you can deduct x from the $100. Your cost basis was $80 so your gain is $20, no matter what x is.

A simpler way of thinking about is just that you bought 1.01 Ether, and sold 1.01 Ether for $100, the transaction happening to include a payment fee built in to it.

Comment: They didn't cause me a problem. It's just the first year I'm doing my Capital Gains taxes and I wanted to confirm my calculations. Thanks so much!

Comment: I guess your statement that it "cannot be deducted" is a bit misleading - it's just a question of perspective. It's *already* been taken into account once you take as your basis the cost of the 1.01 Ether, so it's just that you can't double-count it.